# Are too many self-invoking functions in javascript a bad thing?

Tags: javascript

Is it bad to have too many self-invoking functions in JavaScript?

If they all execute right away (page load) aren't you taking more resources than if you had regular functions and call them when you need them?

Or is that a bug that exists in my head?

For example:

Thousands of these:

```
var DoIT = (function () {
//heavy stuff
} ());
```

VS. Thousands of these:

```
var DoIT = function () {
//heavy stuff
};
```

EDIT #1:

I'm talking about things like

- setting alerts
- creating a jQuery dialog with a large form
- re-sizing things when they need to be resized.

Comment: This is not really an answerable question.  Anything that impacts page load time should be looked at -- but often it's a hard requirement to do certain things at page load...so whatcha gonna do?  Certainly, doing non-critical work at critical times like page load is not optimal.

Comment: How many are we talking about? And are you sure they don't need to be called until later?

Comment: You're talking about anonymous functions. They offer a great method to execute code in an own scope, without leaking variables to the global/parent scope. **EDIT**: The code in your examples are **different**. The first one assigns the return value of the function to `DoIT`, whereas the second block attaches a function to `DoIT`.

Comment: @WillChesterfield: You're on the verge of answering my question. So executing them immediately does take up more resources which is why you're saying it's not optimal?

Comment: @capdragon - no, it doesn't take up *more* resources, but it does use resources (of course).  The issue you will face if you do lots of this is slow page load times, so it's generally a good idea to keep the amount of code that runs at page load time as small as possible (note: sometimes that's lots and lots and lots of code, because that's how it has to be)

Comment: @WillChesterfield: Thanks! You should have placed that in an answer instead of saying that the question was not answerable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those "self executing" functions usually serve as namespaces. Ideally Javascript written in this manner just returns object that holds other functions to be called as necessary, so execution isn't expensive. On the other hand if code at hand really is *heavy stuff* that isn't always needed, than sure, just don't call it right away.